# Android ArrayAdapter.Add method not working

Tags: android, arrays, addition, adapter, android-2.2-froyo

The ArrayAdapter.add() method is not working for me. I am using Eclipse Helios 3.6 with ADT Plugin, Target Source is a Froyo 2.2 emulator and 2.2 HTC Evo 4g. Here is my java class

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class Main extends Activity {

         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            String[] entries = {"List Item A", "List Item B"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, entries);

             arrAdapt.setNotifyOnChange(true);
             arrAdapt.add("List Item C");
        }
    }
```

And here is my layout for the list item (list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:textSize="12sp"
</TextView>
```

It is giving me and error in the LogCat that says

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>   at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:411)
>   at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:432)
>   at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm just learning, but if I'm reading the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java/?v=source) correctly, ArrayAdapter's constructor doesn't copy references to each of the elements in the array or list.  Instead, it directly uses the list that's passed in, or for an array uses [asList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to treat the original array as a list.  Since the list returned by asList() is still just a representation of the underlying array, you can't do anything (such as resize) that you couldn't do with an array.

Try passing a list like ArrayList instead of an array.

```
ArrayList<String> entries = 
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("List Item A", "List Item B"));

ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapt=
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, entries);

arrAdapt.setNotifyOnChange(true);
arrAdapt.add("List Item C");
```

Comment: If this is correct, the ArrayAdapter documentation could be clearer.  There's no mention of the ability to add elements depending on the constructor used.

Comment: You are right, this solved my issues and my ListView within a LinearLayout now works!