# ArrayAdapter addAll function doesn't seem to be invoked

Tags: java, android

My code below is for search filter for a list view. Every time the text in the `tbSearch` editText is changed, the items in the listview must be changed. The execution goes inside the if statement `(txt.length()==0)` but it does not add my array.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String txt = tbSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    aaItems.clear();
    if (txt.length() == 0)
    {
        aaItems.addAll(arrMonth);
    }
    else {
        for (String item : arrMonth) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().contains(txt)) {
                aaItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter?

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125350/android-arrayadapter-add-method-not-working

Comment: that notifyDataSetChanged does not work for me.

Comment: It seems that my arraylist gets cleared and i don't know why. I only clear my arrayadapter, not my arraylist.

Comment: ArrayAdapter calls notifyDataSetChanged for you on both the clear() and addAll() calls and is therefore unnecessary to call yourself.

Comment: You are right @MichaelKrause

Comment: Are you saying your arrMonth list gets cleared?  Would need to see more code that interacts with it in order to determine why. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The List you are passing to your ArrayAdapter is used as **the** backing ArrayList for the adapter.

When you call clear(), you are literally clearing the backing array you gave it.

You'll need to ensure that the list you give the adapter is different than your arrMonth list like so:

```
aaItems = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    new ArrayList<String>(arrMonths));
```

Comment: I tried to create a backup ArrayList but it still gets cleared out.

Comment: So you created a final object which can't be modified. But what if my ArrayList will be coming from a database. That means i cannot use fixed lists like that.

Comment: That's fine.  Just don't use the same ArrayList to hold all the possible values as the one you pass to your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: If you do nothing else - just create a new ArrayList passing it your arrMonth list as an argument when you create your ArrayAdapter and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @PatrickDeVera: I've modified my answer to suit your particular issue.  You should be able to replace your line that creates the ArrayAdapter with mine and be good to go.

Comment: look at my new answer @michael

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem with the help of @Michael Krause. Thanks bro! I copied another arraylist which is temp, and used in inside the textchangedlistener.

```
public class ItemList extends Activity {

    ListView lvItems;
    EditText tbSearch;
    //String[] arrMonth = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    ArrayList<String> arrMonth = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> aaItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        tbSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbSearch);
        PopulateArrayList();
        temp.addAll(arrMonth);

        aaItems = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrMonth);
        lvItems.setAdapter(aaItems);

        tbSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String txt = tbSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                aaItems.clear();
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    aaItems.addAll(temp);
                } else {
                    for (String item : temp) {
                        if (item.toLowerCase().contains(txt)) {
                            aaItems.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void btnAdd_Click(View v)
    {
        aaItems.add("Patrick");
    }

    public void PopulateArrayList()
    {
        arrMonth.add("January");
        arrMonth.add("February");
        arrMonth.add("March");
        arrMonth.add("April");
        arrMonth.add("May");
        arrMonth.add("June");
        arrMonth.add("July");
        arrMonth.add("August");
        arrMonth.add("September");
        arrMonth.add("October");
        arrMonth.add("November");
        arrMonth.add("December");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you Patrick.  I have two requests: If my answer helped you, could you kindly accept my answer?  And secondly, the moderators will probably get on you about answering your own question as opposed to modifying your original question.  Just an FYI.  :)

Comment: @MichaelKrause:  It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.  The main bit here is to see if it really did answer the question, is all.